# How to set the value of date from a calendar in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component Datepicker. What I want to do is set the value attribute of the input element when I clic on a date on the calendar. Here's how I'm using the Datepicker

```
<Datepicker
label={t('birthday')}
name="birthday"
showTimeSelect={false}
minDate="1/1/1920 00:00:00"
onChange={(ev) => {this.handleChangeDate(ev, 'birthday');}}
/>
```

And the function handleChangeDate:

```
  handleChangeDate = (date, name) => {
    const dateValue = date !== null ? date : '';
    this.setState({
      [name]: dateValue,
    });
  };
```

Comment: Please, provide a runnable example. It's not clear what the Datepicker you are using, which API it has etc.

Comment: Unfortunaly I can´t upload a runnable example. Here's the Datepicker component https://www.codepile.net/pile/JXZa417r

Comment: Ok, just provide `selected={this.state.birthday}` into your `Datepicker` component.

Comment: Read more about controlled components in react docs - https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components